# MvvmCross Android: How to create a binding for a subview of a fragment to an arbitrary MvxViewModel?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I searched for quite a time, and didn't found any case to match the problem I'm currently facing.

I have a subclass of MvxFragmentActivity (MainRootView.cs/.axml) that contains an Android navigation drawer layout:

```
public class MainRootView : MvxFragmentActivity, IFragmentHost 
    { 
    ...
    protected override void OnViewModelSet () 
        {
            base.OnViewModelSet ();
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.MainRootView);
            ...
        }
```

In Setup.cs I defined a custom Presenter to control what fragment is shown when a new viewModel get loaded:

```
public interface IFragmentHost
    {
        bool Show (MvxViewModelRequest request);
    }

    public interface ICustomPresenter
    {
        void Register (Type viewModelType, IFragmentHost host);
    }

    public class CustomPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter, ICustomPresenter
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, IFragmentHost> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IFragmentHost>();

        public override void Show (MvxViewModelRequest request) 
        {
            IFragmentHost host;
            if (this.dictionary.TryGetValue (request.ViewModelType, out host)) 
            {
                if (host.Show (request)) 
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            base.Show (request);
        }

        public void Register(Type viewModelType, IFragmentHost host) 
        {
            this.dictionary [viewModelType] = host;
        }
    }
```

Now - in MainRootView.cs - I implemented the Show method for a certain ViewModelRequest, and replace the framelayout content with a certain fragment:

```
public bool Show(Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(OneCertainViewModel)) 
    {
        var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader> ();
        var viewModel = loaderService.LoadViewModel (request, null);

        var oneCertainFragment = new OneCertainFragment ();
        oneCertainFragment.ViewModel = viewModel;

        var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        ft.Replace (Resource.Id.flMainContent, oneCertainFragment);
        ft.Commit ();

        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

The fragment code looks like this:

```
public class HubFragment : MvxFragment 
    {
    ...
    public override global::Android.Views.View OnCreateView(global::Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                                            global::Android.Views.ViewGroup container, 
                                                            Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            global::Android.Views.View view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.HubFragment, null);

            return view;
        }
        ...
```

This fragment contains a small number of dynamically created custom subviews, each one being related to a separate viewmodel, that is being set right after its creation.

```
public class SubSectionView : LinearLayout, IHubSectionView
{
    private MySubViewModel _vm;

    public void SetContentViewModel (MySubViewModel vm) 
    {
        _vm = vm;
        ...
    }
```

Now how can bind a property of a TextView inside of this subview to a property of the viewModel I have set before, if that's possible at all?

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed explanation... However, I'm afraid I still don't quite get what you are trying to do. I don't understand who's creating these views or who's calling `SetContentViewModel`. In general you can add bindings to any view class with some "boilerplate" code like in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs ... but don't know if that applies here or not - don't really understand what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for the hint, and sorry for not being clear enough. SetContentViewModel is being called from the parent fragment that itself is living inside the MvxFragmentActivity. I will have a deep look into the MvxFrameControl class. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As I hope to understand your case, I've had your problem in quite same form:
I have a ViewModel with another SubViewModel as a property; let's call it: `MySubView`

Assume that we have a main view like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

...

<Mvx.MvxFrameControl
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  local:MvxBind="DataContext MySubView"
  local:MvxTemplate="@layout/subview"/>

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using MvxFrameControl is the key here. It binds our property and pass it to specified template. There we may use our SubViewModel's properties.

So all we need is to define `MySubView` in our main viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ...
    private SubViewModel _mySubView = new SubViewModel();
    public SubViewModel MySubView
    { 
        get { return _mySubView; }
        set { _mySubView = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => MySubView); }
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.